# Getting data off Metacritic; arguments imply differing number of rows?

Tags: r

I'm relatively new at this, so I'm just practicing my coding. I'm trying to get data off of Metacritic (just titles and scores), and here's my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
datamatrix=data.frame()

for(i in 0:98) {
  metascores<-as.numeric(html_text(html_nodes(
    read_html(GET(paste0("http://www.metacritic.com/browse/movies/score/metascore/all?page=", i),
        add_headers("User-Agent" = "myagent"))),
    xpath = '//*[(@id = "mantle_skin")]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "positive", " " ))]')))

  metanames<-as.character(html_text(html_nodes(
    read_html(GET(paste0("http://www.metacritic.com/browse/movies/score/metascore/all?page=", i),
        add_headers("User-Agent" = "myagent"))), 
    xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "title", " " ))]//a')))

  metanamesv2<-gsub(" ", "-", metanames)
  metanames.final<-gsub(":", "", metanamesv2)
  data<-data.frame(metascores, metanames.final)

  datamatrix<-rbind(datamatrix, data)
}
```

However, when I try and run this code, I get an error:

```
Error in data.frame(metascores, metanames.final) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 63, 100
```

But this always occurs on different webpages! For example, in the beginning it would stop at page 3, but then I reset everything and it stopped at page 18, and now page 45 (my datamatrix has 4500 observations of 2 variables, whereas before it would have 300 and 1800.) In other words, it seems to have fixed the error occasionally and is able to pull the correct data sometimes. Why is that? Why is it not consistent? Is it the web page messing it up, or the consistent need to go back to a different link?

Please note: Feel free to assess my code! Like I said, I'm literally just starting, so I'm sure all my code is grossly inefficient. I'm also aware of the magrittr package, that's probably the next step in using this, I just wanted to test this stuff out first.

EDIT: Well...I fixed it. Kinda. Feel free to critique my code though.

Comment: The first thing that stands out to me is that your xpaths are kind of arbitrary and non-specific. The thing I noticed around `i=46` or so is that the score div class changes from `metascore_w large movie positive` to `metascore_w large movie mixed`. You are searching for the attribute "positive". That's where your issues are coming from I think.

Comment: @JeffYontz Thanks! I managed to figure it out now, so thankfully it's working.